# Use a TypeScript generic to constrain function arguments without capturing the argument type

Tags: typescript

For a typed SDK I'm building I'd like the required return type of a function to define the function arguments.

The problem is best illustrated using the following example:

```
function select<I extends R,R>(...items: I[]): R {
  return item[0]
}

const r: string | number = select('s', 1)
                                   //  ^
                                   // Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.(2345)
```

[Open in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwKYBtXQDwElGoAeUqYAJsogEoA0VAfABQB0rMJAtsgFyK4DaAXQCUvKogDeAKESIATqigg5Sdqi78ADIKkBfKVIgJkUebxNyYYAOaIAPojAgOAI1RzEAXhQYsURgDkyAE0iACMwkA)

✅ TypeScript correctly infers `R` to `string | number`.

✅ For the first argument it accepts `string | number`.

For the second argument it only accepts either `string` (since `I` is inferred to `string`)

I would like to enforce that each argument satisfies type `R` without informing any of the other argument types.

Comment: Does [this version](https://tsplay.dev/mxk5GN) meet your needs? If so I could write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, this version meets my needs perfectly. It's actually so obvious in hindsight. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here is that TypeScript doesn't like to synthesize [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) types when inferring [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type arguments from multiple candidates.  It's looking at `"s"` and `1` and trying to infer `I`; where `"s"` suggests `string` and `1` suggests `number`.  Instead of synthesizing a union, it just picks the type from the first candidate and then complains.  There is an open request at [microsoft/TypeScript#44312](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44312) to allow unions to be inferred in situations like this, but for now it's not part of the language.

You might think that `R` could be consulted when inferring `I`, since `I extends R`, and `R` is already inferred as the union `string | number`.  But that doesn't happen because [constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) are not used as inference sites, as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#7234](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234).  Right now constraints are only used to *check* inferred types, at which point it's too late for your purposes.

The way I usually proceed here is to refactor the generic types so that there is only *one* candidate.  Instead of making `I` the type of the elements of the array (of which there could be multiple), make it the type of the whole array itself, and then you can compute the element type from it:

```
function select<I extends R[], R>(...items: I): R {
  return items[0]
}
```

If you need the element type you can get it by the [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `I[number]`, since you can read an element from an array by indexing into it with a numeric key.

You can verify that this works:

```
const r: string | number = select('s', 1); // okay
// function select<[string, number], string | number>(
//    items_0: string, items_1: number
// ): string | number
```

Here `R` is inferred as `string | number`, while `I` is inferred as the [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) `[string, number]`, and if you need it, `I[number]` would be `string | number`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwKYBtXQDwElGoAeUqYAJsogEoDaAugDTUB8AFAHScwkC2yAXIlwBKQVUQBvAFCJEAJ1RQQcpN1R8aABjpSAvlKkQEyKPMEm5MMAHNEAH0RgQPAEao5iALwoMWKKwByZACmAEZhAG5EAHpoxDgAawBDAE8pWMRQSFgEH0wcGgsrayYnV3dGFChLG3tHZzc5NnS42UQ1PgB9TXNq4qYO5E7QwTLGlsRRKprbBzH3IA)